# Display current event then descending the order in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have events on a WordPress site. Some events are in the future. currently when I display them they are in the correct order but I am needing the current event to display first then show the rest of the events in descending order.

I appreciate any assistance.

Here is my current code

```
$today = date('dmY');
$args = array (
    'post_type' => 'posts_events',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'       => 'start_date',
            'compare'   => '<=',
            'value'     => $today,
        ),
         array(
            'key'       => 'end_date',
            'compare'   => '>=',
            'value'     => $today,
        )
    ),
);
?>
<!-- CONTENT STARTS -->
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="container_16" id="event-list_container">
    <div class="col_14 prefix_1">
        <?php
            $taxonomy     = 'sbts';
            $orderby      = 'name';
            $show_count   = 1;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
            $pad_counts   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
            $hierarchical = 1;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
            $title        = '';
            $empty        = 0;

            $args = array(
                'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
                'orderby'      => $orderby,
                //'show_count'   => $show_count,
                //'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts,
                'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
                'title_li'     => $title,
                'hide_empty'   => $empty
            );
        ?>
        <ul class="taxonomy-list-links">
            <?php wp_list_categories( $args ); ?>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <?php $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; query_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'posts_events', 'paged' => $paged, 'orderby' => 'meta_value', 'order' => 'desc', 'meta_key' => 'start_date', 'posts_per_page' => 3 )); ?>
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
```

Comment: This code sample is a bit weird, you are overriding not used $args. I am not exactly sure what are you trying to achieve. Should the events go like Mo->Tu->We etc. when today is Mo? Or We->Tu->Mo?

Comment: The events I have range from 2014 to 2016 I need the current or closest event to the current day to appear then under that show the events in descending order.

Comment: then I would advise you to make two queries, in one take only the first event and then in the second one use WP_Query argument _offset_ set to 1 to achieve this result. see [WP_Query docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) for more info